# How to read interpreted data strings in Python?

Tags: python, hex, byte

I want to read all strings from Python file. Example file (/tmp/s.py):

```
s = '{\x7f5  x'
```

Now I try to read the string from my script:

```
import re
find_str = re.compile(r"'(.+?)'")

for line in open('/tmp/s.py', 'r'):
    all_strings = find_str.findall(line)
    print(all_strings) # outputs ['{\\x7f5  x']
```

But I want the string (in this case the byte that is in escaped hex representation) not to be escaped. I want to treat the data was it is in my /tmp/s.py file and to get a string with a interpreted \x7f byte, instead of the literal \x7f, which is right now represented as \\x7f.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd use the `unicode_escape` codec to decode the string the same way Python does when reading a string literal:

```
print(*[s.encode('latin1').decode('unicode_escape') for s in all_strings])
```

Note that `unicode_escape` can only decode from bytes, not from text. The codec is also limited to *Latin-1 source code*, not the default UTF-8.

From the [*Text Encodings* section](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#text-encodings) of the Python `codecs` module:

> `unicode_escape`
>
> Encoding suitable as the contents of a Unicode literal in ASCII-encoded Python source code, except that quotes are not escaped. Decodes from Latin-1 source code. Beware that Python source code actually uses UTF-8 by default.

Demo:

```
>>> s = r'{\x7f5  x'
>>> s
'{\\x7f5  x'
>>> s.encode('latin1').decode('unicode_escape')
'{\x7f5  x'
```

Comment: This is a very good answer and answered exactly what I tried to formulate. Many thanks. Any idea why the Python devs would prefer latin1 over utf8, when python source code is by default in utf8?

Comment: @NikolaiTschacher: I suspect the limitation is a historic one; Python 2 source has traditionally been interpreted as Latin-1 as well. Also, Latin-1 means your bytes are decoded one-on-one to Unicode codepoints, which may be a better choice when dealing with arbitrary strings (you can always decode all bytes to a Unicode codepoint, even if it is the wrong one). You cannot specify the source encoding here as you are already picking the `unicode_escape` codec.